# Confused about this interpretation of U for.a quasilinear utility function

Tags: microeconomics

I'm going through this principles of economics course, and at one point the lecturer gives the following interpretation of $U(x,m)$ where $U(x,m) = B(x)+m$ : "It's just the total amount of dollars that you would have to receive to be indifferent between consuming x and m and not consuming any x", where m is a measure of all the other consumption in dollars.

I don't get this. Why wouldn't someone just have to give me the difference between B(x) and the the money needed to buy x units of the good. This would make up for the additional benefit I'm getting from purchasing B(x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is that $m$ stands for money, which has some value from the possibility of spending it on other stuff.

Under the implicit assumption that $B(0)=0$, that your instructor seems to make,
we get the equality $B(0)+m=B(x)+0$ if the consumer is indifferent between $0$ amount of the first good and $m$ amount of money, or $x$ amount of the first good and no money. Then $m=B(x)$, so $B(x)$ is the amount of money that would compensate the consumer for not having the $x$ amount of the first good.

Money is here not referring to the total expenditure and the argument is not related to what a consumer would actually buy.

Comment: You said "() is the amount of money that would compensate the consumer for not having the  amount of the first good" But the professor gave the interpretation for $U(x,m)$. The statement "It's just the total amount of dollars that you would have to receive to be indifferent between consuming x and m and not consuming any x" is with reference to $U(x,m)$. Here's the video of the lecture for reference. At 8:40 he makes the statement. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WztFR_ESFrI

Comment: @AdamSorolla, yes, that's what he said, but it is obviously just an unfortunate (i.e., wrong) expression of what he most likely wanted to say, namely "It's just the total amount of dollars that you would have to receive to be indifferent between consuming x and m and *neither consuming any x nor any m*."

Comment: @AdamSorolla, PS: In the video, the speaker also provides an incorrect interpretation of $B(x)$ at 5:20. Since he explicitly mentions twice that $B(0)$ need *not* equal $0$, the WTP for $x$ units of the good is not $B(x)$, but $B(x)-B(0)$. The interpretation in his "Remark 1" is only valid for the normalization $B(0)=0$.

Comment: @VARulle Ah. That makes a whole lot more sense - "It's just the total amount of dollars that you would have to receive to be indifferent between consuming x and m and neither consuming any x nor any m" Thank you. The second point you made was actually listed as a correction for the lecture (i.e the B(x) interpretation only being valid for B(0) = 0)

Comment: @VARulle The interpretation I've taken for the second point is, for B(0)=0, B(x) is the maximum amount a consumer would pay for x units of good x. I reasoned as follows: If the total money a consumer has is split into two parts, one going towards m and the other towards buying good x, this only makes sense if B(x) >= just keeping that money and putting it towards m. So the limiting case would be where the benefit B(x) is equal to the money put to obtaining the good. So this is the maximum price, or "willingness to pay for good x"

Comment: @AdamSorolla, yes, the "WTP for consuming $x$ units of the good" is by definition the maximum of the set of prices such that you prefer buying to not buying, i.e. $WTP(x)=\max\{p:\, U(x,m-p)\ge U(0,m)\} = \max\{p:\, p\le B(x)-B(0)\}=B(x)-B(0)$. Thus, if you normalize $B(0)=0$, then $B(x)=WTP(x)$.

Comment: @VARulle Got it. Thank you!